# How to make last row to cover the remaning unoccupied space of tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewautomaticdimension

I have a tableview , it has two rows.

Tableview's height is 700. The first row height is 150 and the second row height is 100 but I'd like the second cell to cover the rest of the space in tableview.

I know I can use the below for tableview height. But I'd like to

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
```

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36501276/how-to-make-last-row-of-uitableview-fill-the-empty-space

Comment: Simply calculate by TableViewheight-firstCellHeight will give height for 2nd Cell to fill whole TabelView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, just replace this method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    
    let tblHeight = infoTable.bounds.size.height
    return indexPath.row == 0 ? 150 : tblHeight - 150
    
}
```

just change infoTable with your table name.